# "double free detected in tcache 2" Error while reallocating a pointer to a dynamic array of strings

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

I have written this code to store a dynamic array of strings on which different operations can be performed. It works correctly when I enter the strings initially and when I add 2 strings, but on the 3rd string it fails each time with the error "free(): double free detected in tcache 2". I haven't freed memory anywhere in the program, so i don't understand why this error is occurring. Also from what I saw after searching about this error, it occurs when the program attempts to free a memory location that has been freed earlier.

The error is occurring due to the realloc statement in the addend() function. But I am unable to grasp what is actually going wrong.

Can someone give a hint as to what I might be doing wrong here. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addend(char** arr,int size) {
    arr = (char **) realloc(arr, (size+1)*sizeof(char *));
    *(arr+size) = (char *) calloc(100, sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter new string to be added : ");
    scanf("%s",*(arr+size));
}

void addbegin(char** arr,int size) {
    arr = (char **) realloc(arr, (size+1)*sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = size; i>0; i--) {
        *(arr+i) = *(arr+i-1);
    }
    printf("Enter new string to be added : ");
    scanf("%s",*(arr));
}

void printarr(char** arr, int size) {
    printf("[");
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%s, ",*(arr+i));
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

void delete() {}

int main() {
    int n;
    printf("Enter the size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    char** arr = (char **) calloc(n,sizeof(char*));

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        *(arr+i) = (char *) calloc(100, sizeof(char));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter the (%d) string to be entered : ",i);
        scanf("%s",*(arr+i));
    }

    int option;
    for (;;) { 
        printf("Choose out of the following options: Add End (1), Add Beginning (2), Delete (3), Length (4), Print Array (5) : ");
        scanf("%d",&option);

        switch(option) {
            case 1:
                addend(arr,n);
                n++;
                break;
            case 2:
                addbegin(arr,n);
                n++;
                break;
            case 3:
                delete();
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("%d",n);
                break;
            case 5:
                printarr(arr,n);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid option, enter again\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `*(arr+i)` is a funny way to spell `arr[i]`. Only use the former forn when ... let me think about an example ... (hours are passing) ...

Comment: Calling realloc on an old address will produce the same error

Comment: Prefer `struct string_buffer { size_t size; char **arr; };` because those values don't mean anything if they're separated. It also helps with three-star. Still not enough allocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void addend(char** array,int size) {
   array = (char **) realloc(array, (size+1)*sizeof(char *));
   /* ... */
```

It does not change the `arr` from the `main` function as `array` (I changed the name intentionally to make a clear distinction between those two variables) is a local variable in the `addend` function scope.

You need to pass the reference to the `arr` to be able to ***modify*** it.

```
void addend(char*** array,int size) {
   *array = realloc(*array, (size+1)*sizeof(**array));
   /* ... */
```

And in the `main` function `addend(&arr,n);`.

You need to amend all other functions (and calls to them) you made the same mistake.

Side notes:

1. You use `realloc` incorrectly. You need to save the result to the temporary variable as `realloc` may fail and you will have a memory leak (as you will not have reference to the previously allocated memory)
2. Do not cast the result of `malloc` and friends. If it does not compile it means that you are compiling C code using C++ compiler and it is not correct.

Comment: `char*** array` may warrant a read through of https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: @Chris the question was not about it